# Trying to build this navigation layout - not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, layout

I want to build a navigation layout like the following, where i have ***nav1 - logo - nav2***, like this: [LAYOUT EXAMPLE](https://dribbble.com/shots/3504491-Ashbry-Music-Festival/attachments/775130)

**The problem:** On wordpress I have the following layout upon which I am trying to get the css (flexbox) to work.

**Laptop screen,** currently, the .site-branding div is on the left while the .main-navigation nav are bothing sitting on the right hand side. **While the layout on laptop screen should be `navigation one | logo | navigation two` (like in the example layout)**

Here is a screen capture...https://i.stack.imgur.com/5n1pR.jpg

**Tablet Screen,** the navigation one is on top while the logo is in the middle and the navigation two is sitting on the bottom...like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdEf1.jpg, **while the logo should be first then both navigation should be on the line below side by side**

***I think the problem is with the flex order property? Or is my media queries inheriting styles it shouldn't? I have checked this but I not sure what is going on, help.***

Please help

HTML

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle">Primary Menu</button>
            <div class="menu-primary-menu-links-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-167" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-167"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/home/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-165" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-165"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/about/">About</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-1987" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1987"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Gallery</a><button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false"><span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span><span class="screen-reader-text">Expand child menu</span></button>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1988" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1988"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/book-a-workshop/">Book A Workshop</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>     </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        <div class="site-branding">
                        <div class="site-branding-text">
                                    <p class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" rel="home">Treehouse</a></p>
                                    <p class="site-description">Its an awesome website</p>
                            </div>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle">Primary Menu</button>
            <div class="menu-primary-menu-links-container"><ul id="primary-menu" class="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-167"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/home/">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-165"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/about/">About</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-1987"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/gallery/">Gallery</a><button class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false"><span class="dropdown-symbol">+</span><span class="screen-reader-text">Expand child menu</span></button>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1988"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/book-a-workshop/">Book A Workshop</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul></div>     </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header>
```

CSS

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# HEADER
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
.site-header {
    position: relative;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
    color:black;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {
    /* HEADER */
    .site-header {
        flex-wrap:  nowrap;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
    }
}

.site-branding {
    min-height: 65px;
 }
.site-title {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1rem;
}

    .site-title a {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .site-title a:hover, .site-title a:focus {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

.site-description {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: .9rem;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 100;   
}

/* Custom Header Image - Uploaded in Customizor */  
.header-image {
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 60vh;
    overflow: hidden; /* Max height of 60vh will make the image overflow and so we crop it off */
}
    .header-image img {
        display: block;
        width: 100vw /* Image to stretch full view port */
    }

/* Custom Logo Image */
.custom-logo-link img {
    display: block;
    height: 65px;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 1rem;
} /* ./end */

.site-branding-text {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 65px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {

    .site-header {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
    .site-branding {
        text-align: center;
        flex:1 100%;
        /*flex: 1 0 auto;  */

        /*Grow to 1 in size, 0 it should NOT shrink in size when the screen is smaller (i.e. squeesh with navigation), auto - the site of container is whatever the size content in it is*/
    }
    #site-navigation {
        margin: auto;
    }

    .main-navigation ul {
        /*flex-wrap: nowrap;*/
    }
}

@media screen  and (min-width: 900px) {
            .main-navigation ul {
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }

        .site-branding {
            flex:0;
        }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1080px) {

        html {
            font-size: 20px;
        }


        .site-branding {
            order: 1;
        }

         /*Navigation Laptop*/
        .nav2 {
            order:0;
        }

        .nav1 {
            order:1;
        }
}
```

Comment: "*Not working?!*" is not a very helpful description of the problem you are having. Please edit your question to explain *exactly* what is going wrong. We can't help fix a problem when we don't know what it is.

Comment: @FluffyKitten thank you for the feedback, I've updated the question now

Comment: As the issue is with the styling of the generated HTML, we need to see the HTML itself rather than the php code that creates it. It would also help us if you could create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), preferably as a [runnable code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - seeing the problem in action makes it easier to debug the issue. Also, your `<nav>` elements both have the same id - ids should be unique (but that's unlikely to be adding to the problem you're having)

Comment: Thank you again, @FluffyKitten. I've added the html rendered code

Comment: Any ideas what the issue is?